# Trigger Analysis Service DataBase Refresh using an XMLA script instead of JSON

Tags: json, ssms, xmla, analysisservices

We have a case scenario where we need an analysis service database to be fully refreshed, except for one table. We're looking for a one-shot command that allows us to do the full refresh without having to manually list all the tables in the database (so as to avoid having to maintain this list), but exclude one or more tables from the refresh sequence.

An adpatation of the standard JSON script generated by SSMS:

```json
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "mydb",
        "table": {"exclude": "FactDeleteMe"}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Where the table to exclude from the refresh would be 'FactDeleteMe'. So far my research seems to indicate that I cannot use a JSON script to trigger the refresh in SSMS. In order to avoid needing another tool/language (e.g. I know this can be done from a Python Script), could this JSON be written as an xmla query? If so, an example would be very helpful.

**EDIT**

I found that you can actually execute this as an MDX script, but the exclude function doesn't seem to work on our service. So if you also know of a way to run the exclude clause in the JSON script that would also help me tons.